# Ограничить просмотр через разные PHP скрипты, папок вне homeDir

Tags: php, права, centos7, httpd

Есть такой скрипт phpFileManager-1.7.8 установил его на сайт для user1, но он через него может смотреть папки и файлы всего сервера. То есть это файловый менеджер на php, через который можно просматривать весь сервер.

centos 7

домен otdel1.site.ru

httpd запускается от user1

home dir = /home/user1/www <- тут сайт otdel1.site.ru

Хочу ограничить пользователей, чтобы они могли используя php скрипты (и не только этот) смотреть только свой каталог /home/user1/www. 
Не могу понять как это делать и с чего начать. Прошу помощи разобраться.

Comment: php как модуль httpd

Answer (score -1):

Сделал так в виртуальном хосте httpd добавил

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
 php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/user1/www/"
</IfModule>
```